# Create a sliding menu

Tags: android, android-layout

i'm trying to create a Sliding Menu for my android app. Well, at this moment i'm not well suceed.

I'm trying to do something like this:

[image]

If  I press button A, in option view will appear A's options, if I press B, same thing happens, C...

Can you help me?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

see this: How to Create QuickAction Dialog in Android : http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/

Answer (score 0):

Simple sliding menu:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="25"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:text="A" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="25"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:text="B" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="25"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:text="C" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="25"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:text="D" />

    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Now set onclick listeners of these buttons in your java code.
If you want to show popups, see [How to create a popup window in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7498605/how-to-create-a-popup-window-in-android)